# how to know at which revision certain line was introduced?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

At Eclipse there is usefull option "Show annotations". Using it I can find at which revision each line of file is created.
How to do the same using visualsvn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate is called "Blame" in subversion. Annotate is a more nicely put alias that some clients support. VisualSVN uses the original "Blame" name of the command on its context menu.

A related (but not duplicate) SO question: ["SVN Blame" plugin for VisualStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/459538/280222)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio:

- Right-click on a file in Solution explorer **| VisualSVN | Blame...**

  or
- Right-click in a code editor **| VisualSVN | Blame...**