# Any experience with Rocket SVN?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn, ankhsvn

I know there is plenty of questions about which plugin to choose for integration SVN to Visual studio:

- [AnkhSVN versus VisualSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045/ankhsvn-versus-visualsvn)
- [Which would you rather use: VisualSVN or AnkhSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102324/which-would-you-rather-use-visualsvn-or-ankhsvn)
- [What Subversion Plugins for Visual Studio are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453481/what-subversion-plugins-for-visual-studio-are-there)
- [Which plugin do you use for SVN in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423687/which-plugin-do-you-use-for-svn-in-visual-studio)

I deciding which plugin to use (I'm long time TFS user). By reading those questions I decided to choose AnkhSVN but by browsing among available plugins I found a new one - [Rocket SVN](http://www.axosoft.com/rocketsvn/visual_studio). I'm just asking if anybody already have some experience and can compare Rocket SVN with AnkhSVN. That plugin probably didn't exist at time of asking mentioned questions.

Comment: have you tries Rocket SVN? What are your thoughts? Thanksfor sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RocketSVN is just re-branded version of AnkhSVN:
http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=578&dsMessageId=365321