# When you move files around in Visual Studio will Ankh SVN turn that into a SVN move?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I would like to move some files around in Visual Studio. But I see Ankh is treating that as new files and delete in the changes list. Is the equivalent to SVN move? I don't want to loose the history for those files.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010/is-ankhsvn-any-good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should treat a move as a *copy* and delete.  This would be equivalent to the way SVN handles moves.  Check to see if it truly thinks it's a new file, or if it thinks it's a copied file.  There should be an option when viewing the file's history to view the history as it persists through copies.

Comment: This answer is obsolete in newer SVN versions. Copy/move tracking.